# Spring ROO chained (dynamic) combobox

Tags: java, select, dynamic, spring-roo

I am starting with Spring ROO now, and I need to add a couple chained comboboxes.
I have the Country and State comboboxes inside one page.

I would like the STATE select to be populated based on the COUNTRY previously selected value.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an automatic way to do that. You must do it by hand.